# pass square brace to uplevel TCL

Tags: tcl, stack-trace, procedure

I have a code in which I am passing a list to be evaluated, by TCl uplevel #0.
While it works well if I give it a code which uses curly braces in order to wrap the square braces, for example:

```
uplevel #0 { puts [ info vars CCK_* ] }
```

I cannot get to accept when I use a list, i.e.:

```
uplevel #0 [list puts "\[" info vars CCK_* "\]" ]
```

I get:

```
wrong # args: should be "puts ?-nonewline? ?channelId? string"
    while executing
"puts {[} info var CCK_* \]"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [ list puts "\[" info var CCK_* "\]" ]"
```

I need the list command , because some of the rest of the code requires evaluation of variable names, that must happen before uplevel takes order ( i.e., input to uplevel). For example:

```
if { [ getpoint $elem ] == $pointy }
```

when  `[ getpoint $elem ]` is to be evaluated in the uplevel, but pointy actually is defined and set in the calling proc , hence I cannot use curly braces for it, there will be evaluation before uplevel is called, and it would get just a number.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assembling a script (or command sequence) to be submitted to uplevel etc. is not necessarily best achieved using `list`. This is the case for a script with nested evaluations, for instance.

Your question wording is not fully clear to me (so I might have interpreted it incorrectly), but you might want to consider using `[subst]` or `[string map]` for your purposes?

Watch:

```
set CCK_1 ""

proc foo {someVarName} {
    uplevel "#0" [subst -nocommands {
    if {"$someVarName" in [info vars CCK_*]} {
        puts "Found $someVarName"
    }
   }]
}

foo CCK_1; # prints "Found CCK_1"
foo CCK_2
```

List are better suited for command sequences without excessive evaluation nesting; for complete scripts, better use script templates based on `[subst]` or `[string map]`. A word of caution: `[subst]` and `[string map]` don't protect the substitution values and position them in the script in their literal form.

### Update

This is not to say that your original snippet could not be made to work:

```
set CCK_1 ""
# a) non-robust variant
proc bar {pattern} {
    uplevel "#0" puts "\[info vars $pattern\]"
    # equiv of
    uplevel "#0" [concat puts "\[info vars $pattern\]"]
    # versus
    uplevel "#0" [list puts "\[info vars $pattern\]"]
}

bar CCK_*

set "CCK _1" ""
# b) robust variant
proc bar-robust {pattern} {
    uplevel "#0" puts "\[[list info vars $pattern]\]"
    # equiv of
    uplevel "#0" [concat puts "\[[list info vars $pattern]\]"]
}

bar-robust "CCK _*"
```

`uplevel` assembles the script to be evaluated by `[concat]`ing its arguments. Like providing a single `[concat]`'ed the argument. You would not use `list` here to assemble the entire script, but rather to protect the script components under assembly (see `bar-robust`). Protection here means that complex values are maintained in their original meaning during script assembly (e.g., a match pattern incl. whitespace: `CCK _*`).

Comment: For the sake of completeness: `[format]` is also a valid candidate.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: subst gave me what I have wanted, with minimal changes, Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You can only use the `list` command to build a *single substitution-free* command. It quotes everything for you specifically to do just that, and `puts [info vars CCK_*]` is a compound command. There are a few ways around this, but you should think carefully about what you're really doing:

<sup>I've quoted the `#0` for reasons of highlighting only.</sup>

### Only `uplevel` What Needs It

```
puts [uplevel "#0" [list info vars CCK_*]]
```

Or in this case:

```
puts [uplevel "#0" {info vars CCK_*}]
```

### Wrap The Compound In `eval`

You can send arbitrary stuff like this, but I'm not sure *why* you'd do it:

```
uplevel "#0" [list eval { puts [ info vars CCK_* ] }]
```

### Send A Lambda Term

```
uplevel "#0" [list apply {{} {
    set vars [uplevel 1 {info vars CCK_*}]
    puts $vars
}}]
```

It's not so useful here, but when you're wanting to send in arbitrary additional value from the current scope it becomes *superb:*

```
set value "this is a {complex string with \[some bits\] that might} make \$tcl choke"
uplevel "#0" [list apply {{value} {
    set vars [uplevel 1 {info vars CCK_*}]
    puts $value
    puts $vars
    puts $value
}} $value]
```

Comment: Also noteworthy: A lambda term does not pollute the scope of execution of the `[uplevel]`'ed script (e.g., with temporary or auxiliary variables like `vars`).

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to run the code in two steps. First, run the code in the square brackets, then use the result of that in the second call. Of course, since you're only doing a `puts`, there's no need to run that via `uplevel`:

```
set result [uplevel #0 [list info vars CCK_*]
puts $result
```

If using `puts` was for illustrative purposes, then I think the general idea of calling `uplevel` twice is still valid: run the code in square brackets as a distinct step, then combine it with your other code to get the final result.

Comment: Except you virtually never need to `uplevel` the `puts`, not unless you're in a namespace that has redefined it to do something else, which is possible but _quite_ unusual…

Comment: @DonalFellows: true. I realized my mistake a few minutes after writing the original draft of that answer. I've updated it. Thanks!

Comment: The puts was purely descriptive